# Tracking Issuer of Corda State

Tags: corda

Is there a way in a Corda Contract where I can check if the issuer is a particular party only. Say I have a network of 3 nodes-NodeA,NodeB,Notary. Can I check in a contract whether the issue is done by PartyA only
i.e the issuing key of the issuer is always equal to PartyA's issuing key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can perform this check. For example:

```
class IssuedContract : Contract {
    companion object {
        // Used to identify our contract when building a transaction.
        const val ID = "com.issuing.IssuedContract"
    }

    private val expectedIssuer = CordaX500Name("Expected Issuer", "London", "GB")

    override fun verify(tx: LedgerTransaction) {
        val issuedStates = tx.outputsOfType<IssuedState>()
        issuedStates.forEach { issuedState ->
            if (issuedState.issuer.name != expectedIssuer)
                throw IllegalArgumentException("The state is not issued by the correct party.")
        }
    }
}
```

However, this approach would be brittle. The contract would only work specifically for the named issuer.

In general, it would be better for each node to check whether they are happy with the chosen issuer before signing transactions in flows.

Comment: So if we donot use this approach the only other alternative would be to check in the acceptor flow of a counterparty node?